# subscript out of range error when using sheets function

Tags: excel, vba

I got a "Subscript out of range error" while running a code that I wrote.
The faulty code line was:
`value = Sheets("name_of_sheet").Range("C2").value`

The strange thing for me is that this exact code worked daily for a year now without any problem.
Changing "Sheets" to "Worksheets" solved the problem, so I am sure that the sheet name is OK.

Can someone explain this please?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using "value" as a variable?

Comment: And you haven't changed the name of the sheet?  I'd almost expect that to work in reverse while using the sheets position.  A `Sheet` refers to any kind of sheet - chart sheet, macro sheet or a worksheet (a _normal_ sheet), a `worksheet` just refers to the _normal_ sheets containing cells.  So if the first sheet was a chart sheet and the second a worksheet then `Sheets(2)` would work as there's two sheets, but `Worksheets(2)` would throw that error as one of the sheets is a chart sheet.

Comment: Funny sheetname: name_of_sheet

Comment: @Luuklag.  I'm hoping that was just a place-holder, if `name_of_sheet` is a variable then yep, that the answer... can't believe I didn't even consider that possibility.

Comment: @Davesexcel Is it forbidden?

Comment: @JohnyL It's not forbidden but can cause you issues. Don't use VBA syntax as your variable names

Comment: @Tom I know it) Davesexcel just needed to give the explanation to his question

Comment: `Sheets` refers to the currently active workbook, so you can get that error if you don't specify the workbook.

Comment: "name_of_sheet" wasn't the real name. The real name was in Hebrew, I suspected that not every one here reads Hebrew so I just put something for reference. Same goes for value. The real variable was some word in Hebrew written in English letters, so I changed it to avoid unrelated questions. Shouldn't have change it to "value" of course. Maybe I should have specify the workbook as well, still the strange thing is that it worked in the past.